# JText - multilingual string order

Tags: joomla-3.x, language, multilingual, jtext

I have an extension that displays the time a shout was posted, for example:

> 1 day ago

This string is generated in my helper like so:

```
$num . ' ' . JText::_('SHOUT_TIME') . ' ' . JText::_('SHOUT_AGO')
```

The language constants are as follows:

```
SHOUT_TIME="day"
SHOUT_AGO="ago"
```

Now, in English this is perfectly fine, however in let's say, German, `ago` translates into `vor`.

The result of this would be `1 tag vor`, however it **should** be `vor 1 tag`.

Bare in mind that `SHOUT_TIME`, could be one of the following:

- second
- minute
- hour
- day
- month
- year

so this needs to be a separate language string.

---

So how can I switch the string around to cater for other language without using conditional statements in the helper?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Add further abstraction.

```
JText::sprintf('COM_MYCOMPONENT_DATETIME_AGO', $num, JText::_('SHOUT_TIME'), JText::_('SHOUT_AGO'));
```

English language

```
COM_MYCOMPONENT_DATETIME_AGO="%1$s %2$s %3$s"
```

German language

```
COM_MYCOMPONENT_DATETIME_AGO="%3$s %1$s %2$s"
```